# gosmore results to database

Tags: bash, sqlite, openstreetmap

I have a strange request. I need to query gosmore and save results to sqlite database, it sounds simple, but the format is not so simple. The idea is to save this as a binary blob (lat, lon pairs in binary float representation) and calculate time and distance on the way. It must be done in bash so this is actualy a tricky part. As you probably know, the result from gosmore looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain

52.454918,16.953721,J,residential,675,Rubież
52.454502,16.953466,J,residential,665,Bronisza
52.454577,16.947981,J,residential,620,Bronisza
52.454577,16.947885,J,secondary,616,Naramowicka
52.453985,16.947880,J,secondary,610,Naramowicka
52.453596,16.947877,J,secondary,606,Naramowicka
52.453140,16.947873,J,secondary,601,Naramowicka
52.453031,16.947872,j,secondary,601,Naramowicka
52.452947,16.947871,J,secondary,598,Naramowicka
52.452869,16.947871,J,secondary,596,Naramowicka
52.452169,16.947836,J,secondary,592,Naramowicka
52.452119,16.947834,J,secondary,591,Naramowicka
52.452098,16.947833,j,secondary,591,Naramowicka
52.451817,16.947819,j,secondary,589,Naramowicka
52.451746,16.947817,J,secondary,587,Naramowicka
...
```

Column 1 is latitude.
Column 2 is longitude.
Column 5 is time from previous point.

The table to which I need to put it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Route" (
    "StartLatitude" float NOT NULL,
    "StartLongitude" float NOT NULL,
    "EndLatitude" float NOT NULL,
    "EndLongitude" float NOT NULL,
    "TimeSeconds" int,
    "Distance" float,
    "RoutePoints" blob,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_Route" PRIMARY KEY ("StartLatitude", "StartLongitude", "EndLatitude", "EndLongitude")
)
```

I don't assume that you will solve this for me, but maybe you will point me in right direction.

### EDIT 1:

@CL: This suppose to look this:

```
INSERT INTO "Route" VALUES(52.454918, 16.953721, 52.451796, 16.947887, 3600, 5.982, X'D6D1514238A18741...');
```

`Distance` column contains sum of distances between points in kilometers. Distance between points is counted using [Great Circle Distance Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance). If there is better and faster method, I will also take suggestions in that matter.

`RoutePoints` column is representation of each waypoint (lat, lon) as a blob containing pairs of float values (4 bytes per value, 8 chars in HEX string)

Comment: Please show how your example data would look like in the target table.

Comment: Uhm, why bash? And where does the *TimeSeconds* come from? The duration depends on various things additionally to the distance, for example speed limits.

Comment: Each row has a time from previous row at column 5, which I wrote above, so it just requires summing this, as for bash...well why not? I have a highly restricted access to this machine, so bash seam's like a reasonable choice. But I don't exclude perl or python.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Iterating over every line while storing interesting fields from the previous line to access them later is not a big deal. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at counting distance between points and representing points as hex string. But we had to do it quickly any way, so I wrote a patch to gosmore adding new output format. the question remains as a exercise. Is it possible to achieve that in bash :D